# Can't determine type for tag in navigation menu

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I upgraded my android studio to 4.0.1 and gradle to 6.6. I am getting this error

```
Can't determine type for tag '<item android:title="Menu">
    <menu>
        <item android:icon="@drawable/dashboard" android:id="@+id/dashoard" android:title="Dashboard"/>
        <item android:icon="@drawable/hire" android:id="@+id/hire_mechanic_id" android:title="Hire a Mechanic"/>

    </menu>
</item>'
```

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a namespace in the menu element.
See sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/action_favorite"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```